# google maps api loading map on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to initialize the map load on a simple button click but with no luck. Also no errors being thrown in the javascript console.

If I change it to `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` it works fine.

```js
var showMap = $('#show-map');

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
     center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
     zoom: 8
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(showMap, 'click', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 30em;
  width: 30em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCgxY6DqJ4TxnRfKjlZR8SfLSQRtOSTxEU"></script>

<button id="show-map">Show Map</button>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `google.maps.event` handlers for buttons, use a jQuery event listener. Even though it is possible to use Google maps event handlers for the rest of the DOM, it is better practice to use jQuery for this. Also, I think that Sebastián Rojas made a good suggestion about using `window.onload`.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwinkelman/gabkawys/). The only change from the original code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show-map').on('click',initialize)
});
```

This code waits until the `document` is loaded, and then it assigns the event listener to the button (`#show-map`), to do `initialize` when it is clicked.

Comment: _"Google Maps listeners are specific to map elements"_ - not strictly true.  `addListener()` is, but you can also use `addDomListener()`. See [Listening to DOM Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents) in the documentation

Answer (score 5):

You can't replace the event of initialization, because is important that the window is loaded and Google Maps API also. So, instead, leave the dom listener as documentations suggest, and when the event is fired attach an event listener to the button click to show the map

```js
function initialize() {

    //Add the event listener after Google Mpas and window is loaded
    $('#show-map').click(function () {
         var mapOptions = {
     center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
     zoom: 8
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 30em;
  width: 30em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCgxY6DqJ4TxnRfKjlZR8SfLSQRtOSTxEU"></script>

<button id="show-map">Show Map</button>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't seem to find it in the docs. I just saw an example of them attaching an alert event on map click using the method I tried so I thought it might have worked with the map load.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=es#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3 My aswers is what you need?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick-fix, this will work:

```
var map = document.getElementById('show-map')
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', initialize);
```